# Using Airbnb's JavaScript styling guide in Eclipse without Babel

Tags: eclipse, eslint-config-airbnb, tern

How can I use the [Airbnb JavaScript styling guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) without using any additional tools? I already installed Tern (Tern IDE) for my Eclipse oxygen. I downloaded the latest release of the [eslint-config-airbnb-base-v12.0.1](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/releases/tag/eslint-config-airbnb-base-v12.0.1) and selected under
Project -> Properties -> Tern ->Validation -> ESLint the `.eslintrc` file from the release. My Tern configuration is stored in a `.tern-project` file:

```
{
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "plugins": {
    "guess-types": {
      
    },
    "outline": {
      
    },
    "eslint": {
      "configFile": "C:\\dev\\workspace\\pyqt_web\\eslint-config-airbnb-base\\.eslintrc"
    },
    "browser-extension": {
      
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      
    }
  },
  "libs": [
    "browser",
    "jquery"
  ]
}
```

The `.eslintrc` looks like:

```
{
  "extends": "./index.js",
  "rules": {
    // disable requiring trailing commas because it might be nice to revert to
    // being JSON at some point, and I don't want to make big changes now.
    "comma-dangle": 0
  },
}
```

and `index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    './rules/best-practices',
    './rules/errors',
    './rules/node',
    './rules/style',
    './rules/variables',
    './rules/es6',
    './rules/imports',
  ].map(require.resolve),
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2017,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true,
    },
  },
  rules: {
    strict: 'error',
  },
};
```

From here i dont know how to go further. I would expect, that i get new warning which match these of airbnb style guide. Would this work for js code in html files?

Comment: have you had a chance to resolve it? Interesting that airbnb always supposes babel is used